# Accessing route for form submit in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i am trying to access one route like `pages.trashmultiple` this in my view. But its throwing error of `Route [pages.trashmultiple] not defined.`. Here is how my view looks like:

```
    {!!Form::open([
                'method' => 'put',
                'route' => 'pages.trashmultiple'
    ])!!}

<th class="table-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="group-checkable" data-set="#sample_3 .checkboxes"/>
</th>

{!!Form::close()!!}
```

This is how my controller looks like:

```
 public function trashmultiple(Request $request){
        //return "trash multiple page";
        return Input::all();
  }
```

And this is how my routes look like:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    Route::get('pages/trash', 'PagesController@trashpage');

    Route::get('pages/movetotrash/{id}', 'PagesController@movetotrash');

    Route::get('pages/restore/{id}', 'PagesController@restore');

    Route::get('pages/trashmultiple', 'PagesController@trashmultiple'); //this is not working

    Route::resource('pages', 'PagesController');

});
```

When i load my url http://localhost:8888/laravelCRM/public/pages it shows me this below error:

```
ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 307:
Route [pages.trashmultiple] not defined. (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravelCRM/resources/views/pages/pages.blade.php)
```

I want to know why i am unable to access the `pages.trashmultiple` when i have already defined it.

Is there any way i can make it accessible through `pages.trashmultiple`?

Thank you! (in advance)

Comment: Is your view correctly name pages/trashmultiple.blade.php ?

Comment: Yes its correctly named. The below answers are working for me. But the only issue is its keep redirecting me to UPDATE() function of my controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chnage your route to like this:

```
Route::get('pages/trashmultiple', 'PagesController@trashmultiple');
```

To

```
Route::get('pages/trashmultiple', [
    'as' => 'pages.trashmultiple', 'uses' => 'PagesController@trashmultiple'
]);
```

Comment: Yes its kind of working but it started taking me to another function which is update() with in `PagesController`. Why is that? Do i need to change my form submit method from PUT to PATCH?

Comment: I guess whenever we use PUT or PATCH method it redirect us to `update()` function

Answer (score 0):

Change your route so that it becomes:

```
 Route::get('pages/trashmultiple', 
    ['as'=>'pages.trashmultiple',
     'uses'=>'PagesController@trashmultiple']);
```